# Tkinter boot up window

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a boot up window in tkinter. While the program is running through its check list I want to display confirmation that each step has been successful and also that the user does not think the program has hung up waiting for the main screen. Then it must close the window and carry on to the main program.

Everything I have tried only displays the results in a window once the loop has completed. Is there a way to have the results shown, line at a time, 1 second delay between each step before going on to the main program? have I chosen the wrong method perhaps?

so far I have got the following excerpt from my larger program

```
def check_presets_path():
    if os.path.isdir("Presets"):
        #Directory exists
        print("Here at Preset Paths")
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Preset Directory OK...').pack()#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Presets", message = 'Presets sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

##############################################################################################################
def check_text_files_for_emails_path():
    if os.path.isdir("Text Files for Emails"):
        #Directory exists
        label = Label(boot_window, text = 'Text Files for Emails Directory OK...').pack()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Text Files for Emails sub-directory", message = 'Text Files for Emails sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

###############################################################################################################

def check_log_files_path():
    if os.path.isdir("Log Files"):
        #Directory exists
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Log Files Directory OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Log Files sub-directory", message = 'Log Files sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

###############################################################################################################

def check_database_path():
    if os.path.isdir("Database"):
        #Directory exists
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Database Directory OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Database Sub-Directory", message = 'Database sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

##################################################################################################################################
#CHECK IF FILES EXIST AND ARE IN THE CORRECT DIRECTORY/SUB-DIRECTORY
def check_logo_ico():
    if os.path.isfile("Presets/logo.ico"):
        #Is valid
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Logo file OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Presets/logo.ico", message = 'logo.ico in the presets sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

###################################################################################################################################
#CHECK IF FILES EXIST AND ARE IN THE CORRECT DIRECTORY/SUB-DIRECTORY

def check_database_db():
    if os.path.isfile("Database/address_book.db"):
        #Is valid
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Address Book Database OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Database/address_book.db", message = 'address_book.db in the Database sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()

#########################################################################################################################################

def check_button_logo_png():
    if os.path.isfile("Presets/button_logo.png"):
        #Is valid
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Button Logo OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showerror(title="Presets/button_logo.ico", message = 'button_logo.ico in the presets sub-directory does not exist')
        exit()


#########################################################################################################################################

def check_companydetails_text():
    try:
        f = open('Presets/CompanyDetails.txt')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showinfo(title="Company Details.txt", message = 'CompanyDetails.txt in the Presets sub-directory cannot be found')
        exit()
    else:
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Company Details File OK...')#.grid()
        time.sleep(1)
        f.close()   

#########################################################################################################################################

def check_emailsettings_txt():
    try:
        f = open('Presets/EmailSettings.txt')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showinfo(title="Email settings.txt", message = 'EmailSettings.txt in the Presets sub-directory cannot be found')
        exit()
    else:
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Email Settings File OK...').pack()
        time.sleep(1)
        f.close() 

#########################################################################################################################################

def check_runlog_txt():
    try:
        f = open('Log Files/RunLog.txt')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        MsgBox = messagebox.showinfo(title="Run Log.txt", message = 'RunLog.txt file cannot be found')
    else:
        Label(boot_window, text = 'Run Log File OK...').pack()
        time.sleep(1)
        f.close() 

########################################################################################################################################
# DISPLAY BOOT UP WINDOW ###############################################################################################################
########################################################################################################################################

def do_checking():
    check_text_files_for_emails_path()
    check_presets_path()
    check_log_files_path()
    check_database_path()
    check_logo_ico()
    check_database_db()
    check_button_logo_png()
    check_companydetails_text()
    check_emailsettings_txt()
    check_runlog_txt()


boot_window = Tk()
boot_window.title('BOOT WINDOW')
boot_window.geometry("250x350+700+200")

Label(boot_window, text = 'Checking Directory and Files').pack()

do_checking()
boot_window.after(10000, boot_window.destroy)

boot_window.mainloop()

main_program()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i highly recommend you read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines and become familiar with how to properly format Python code.

I also recommend you read about [threading.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html)

You need to create a new thread that runs these checks. Otherwise you will run your checks before ever running your `boot_window`. You need to send your `boot_window` as a parameter to these other functions.

```
# at top...
import threading
# now down low...
boot_window = tk.Tk()
boot_window.title('BOOT WINDOW')
boot_window.geometry("250x350+700+200")
boot_window.after(10000, boot_window.destroy)
Label(boot_window, text='init text...').grid(row=1)
# New thread...
t = threading.Thread(target=do_checking, args=[boot_window])
t.start() # start your do_checking thread
boot_window.mainloop()
```

Then your `do_checking` will have an param for the `boot_window`.

```
def do_checking(wind):
    check_presets_path(wind, 2)
    time.sleep(1)
    check_next_thing(wind, 3)
    time.sleep(1)
    # etc...
```

Then each function will take the assigned row and place the label into your `wind`

```
def check_presets_path(wind, row):
      if os.path.isdir('some_dir'):
          Label(wind, text = 'some_dir exists').grid(row=row)
      else:
          # message box stuff
```

This should get you started but you will have to get a deeper understanding of threading if you want to successfully build a your GUI

Comment: Thank you, i will read up on those two suggestions. Thank you, this solution works perfectly.

Comment: For formatting, I still have a lot to learn, I have tried to keep things really readable for myself and break it into small pieces to help problem solving. I have only been learning programming for 8 or 9 odd weeks and Python gave me the confidence to try it. Just seems so readable to work out how things work. I don't really 'program', but more finding a solution elsewhere and adapting it to my requirements. I really have learned a lot already doing this. I will definitely learn more about threading as my project for this week. Thanks again Matt M

Comment: No problem. Your formatting is good for newcomer intuition. But when you follow the official guidelines (like 80 chars per line) that may initially seem less intuitive, you will find yourself becoming more efficient at reading code. Especially other people's code. It also helps others diagnose your code as well. As for threading, google some beginner tutorials to start.

Comment: Thank you Matt. I have watched a few You-tube beginners videos on Threading and have a better understanding of the concept now. Very useful. Thanks for the guidance.